# ¿como crear otro proyecto en react sin instalar todo de nuevo?

Tags: reactjs

dejenme ponerles en contexto. empeze hace poco en reactjs, instale nodejs, y demas cosas pertinentes para poder crear mi primer proyecto, y lo hice. pero ahora quiero practicar todo lo que vi en otro proyecto.

vi que en varias paginas sugerian poner el siguiente comando `npm install -g create-react-app "nombre"`, esto para poder crear otro projecto supuestamente,¿es asi?.

Si pongo esta linea de codigo en la temrinal ¿no lo estaria instalando todo de nuevo?, por otra parte, si hago esto. ¿se borra mi proyecto anterior?. no entiendo mucho de react aun, yo solo quiero otra carpeta para practicar en otro proyecto react.

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero regresar a la carpeta principal donde tienes alojada la carpeta de tu proyecto actual y abrir la terminal desde esa carpeta para crear tu otro proyecto.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola buenas, para crear otro proyecto ahi, solo debo poner npm install -g creater-react-app??